# Node-Fetch - Danish Letters bad JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, escaping

I'm trying to make a few query's on a Real Estate Website.

When i make the fetch request with words like `'Næstved','Præstø',Karrebæksminde`, i get a bad response because `æ,ø` etc gets replaced by `?` symbol ??? I tried to escape the response and it seems to work at times ... but i mostly get empty responses....

You can try yourself to make a query here: https://home.dk/umbraco/backoffice/home-api/BoligOrAddress/Boligdata?max=100&searchstring=N%C3%A6stved

Here is the code:

```
var cities = [
  'København',
  'København K',
  'Næstved'
];

var promises = cities.map(city => 
fetch(`https://home.dk/umbraco/backoffice/home-api/BoligOrAddress/Boligdata?max=1000000000&searchstring=${city}`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(validate => { if(validate.Successed && validate.Status === 'OK') return validate })
.then(pushAlll => { pushedSuggestions.push(pushAlll); return pushAlll })

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

The problem is i get results like this `{ suggest: 'N�stved', count: ''}`
When i should be getting this:

```
[
    {
    suggest: "Næstved kommune",
    count: "854"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstved, 4700",
    count: "406"
    },
    [
    {
    suggest: "Næstved Landevej, 4243 Rude",
    count: "1"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstved Landevej, 4250 Fuglebjerg",
    count: "1"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstvedvej, 4100 Ringsted",
    count: "2"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstvedvej, 4230 Skælskør",
    count: "3"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstvedvej, 4684 Holmegaard",
    count: "2"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstvedvej, 4720 Præstø",
    count: "4"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstvedvej, 4750 Lundby",
    count: "1"
    },
    {
    suggest: "Næstvedvej, 4760 Vordingborg",
    count: "4"
    }
]
```

Comment: When I click your API link the response seems ok, eg `{"suggest":"Næstved kommune","count":"854"}` - could it be a browser/codepage/unicode problem?

Comment: The response looks just fine with `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8`. Could it be a problem with your console?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys ! I was not encoding the letters into UTF8 so I ended up using an encoder module to do just that.

```
const utf8    = require('utf8')
fetch(`https://home.dk/umbraco/backoffice/home-api/BoligOrAddress/Boligdata?max=1000000000&searchstring=${utf8.encode(city)}`)
```

Thank you for pointing that out @Bergi

Cheers !